# fitting high dim copula to residuals of a garch model very slow in R

Tags: correlation, garch, fitting, computational-statistics, copula

I'm looking for some help on understanding on the fitting procedure of a normal (or any other for that matter) copula in R. My main goal is to either improve computational speed, or revise my strategy.
My current set up is as follows.

- I have $n$ assets (say 100), and compute logreturns of my data for the past $m$ (say 1000) days.
- I fit a GARCH(1,1) model to these returns.
- I fit a Generalized Pareto Distribution to tails of the standardized residuals and a normal distribution for the interior,and use the fitted CDF then to map them in $[0,1]$.
- To each of these $m$ values between zero and one for each asset, I would like to fit a copula, to then sample from the copula many "forecasts".
- I then move on to use those forecasts after 'reversing' all previous steps, to get a distribution of the returns of each asset, while keeping in mind the dependencies of the copula.

I implemented this in R with the `copula`-package using fitcopula, and the `fGARCH` package for the copula.

Now fitting the copula takes a really long time when I start to increase $n$, which is a problem as I want to use a rolling window for my out of sample data, fitting a copula for each time-step. I parrellized the process of fitting the garch-model, but have not found a way to parralelize the the fitting process.

the fitting process is done by maximum likelihood to my understanding. 
My question for now is as follows:

Is there any way I can improve my speed of the fitcopula command? I tried passing a start of the optimization method using the correlations. Made it some what faster, but still not something to write home about...